Show that for two quadratic polynomials p(x) and q(x) with integer coefficients and an non-rational root in common there exists rational $r$ ...
Question: Let $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ be two quadratic polynomials with integer coefficients. Suppose they have a non-rational zero in common. Show that $p(x) = rq(x)$ for some rational number $r$
My attempt: Let us assume $\alpha$ to be the common root and $\beta_1 , \beta_2$ to be the other roots of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$. Then,
$p(x) = (x-\alpha)(x-\beta_1)$
$q(x) = (x-\alpha)(x-\beta_2)$
We now need to prove that there exists $r$ such that,
$(x-\alpha)(x-\beta_1)=r(x-\alpha)(x-\beta_2) \implies (x-\beta_1)=r(x-\beta_2)$
now equations are linear and i know $r$ would be equal to $\dfrac{x-\beta_1}{x-\beta_2}$ is which would be rational but I don't know if this $r$ exists also is my proof correct so far.
The chapter I got this problem into was quadratic equations not on polynomials (and I do not know much about polynomials) so please try not to use polynomial identities in answers. Thanks!!!

Hint: say $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $q(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$ and that they share a non-rational root $\alpha$. Write down $Ap(\alpha)-aq(\alpha)$ in full. Can you go from there?

If a quadratic polynomial $p(x)$ has roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$ you can conclude that $p(x) = {\color{red} A} (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$

If you have a non-rational root in common, say $\alpha$, then the other root of the polynomial has to be $\bar{\alpha}$, the (quadratic) conjugate of $\alpha$ (because the coefficients are from $\mathbb{Z}$). In essence, the two polynomials will share BOTH roots.
This means
\begin{align}
p(x)& =a(x-\alpha)(x-\bar{\alpha}) && \text{ for some } a \in \mathbb{Z}\\
q(x)& =A(x-\alpha)(x-\bar{\alpha}) && \text{ for some } A \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align}
Now the given claim follows from this.
NOTE: $a(\alpha+\bar{\alpha}) \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a\,\alpha \bar{\alpha} \in \mathbb{Z}$ (same for $A$).

The result you are quoting is effectively what they are being asked to prove.

According to the given information about the two quadratic equations, we already know that p(x) and q(x) have a common  intersection point or a root that is not rational , and another point is that their coefficients are integers.
First step : rearrange equations
$P(x)= ax^2 + bx + c$
$ Q(x)=Ax^2 +Bx+C$
Combine the coefficients:
$(a-Ar)x^2 + (b-Br)x + (c-Cr)=0$
Write down the quadratic formula :
$x = \frac{-(b-Br) \pm
\sqrt{(b-Br)^2 - 4(a-Ar)(c-Cr} }{2(a-Ar)}$
At first , without r ,we assume there is a common irrational root which implies that the discriminant part always yields non perfect squares because values of coefficients are integers( Note: had they been fractions , we could have got perfect squares )
If coefficients were fractions for example: look at this discriminant
$(0.5)^2 -4(0.4)(0.1) $ returns a perfect square 0.09
Moving on , if r is rational we are always going to get irrational part and hence irrational root .
Hint: the discriminant part will always yield a whole number that is not a perfect square, if a, b and c are integers . You can check it for yourself. Any multiple of 4 added to or subtracted from a perfect square( b^2) result in a non perfect square
On the contrary, if r was an irrational the quadratic formula would not guarantee the nature of roots because combined coefficients would become irrational after being multiplied by r( You can also give the properties of irrational numbers a read for clarification) .
Operations like ( add, subtract, multiply and divide ) between  only irrationals do not necessarily return irrational number always .
Let us consider a case: If (b-Br) is Pi  ,discriminant is 0  and 2(a-Ar) is 2 Pi , we get a single rational root which is 0.5

We know that $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c, q(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + C$ for some integers $a,b,c,A,B,C$, and that $a \ne 0, A \ne 0$, since both polynomials are quadratic, not linear. By the quadratic formula, we know that the roots of $p$ and $q$ are
$$\dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a},\qquad \dfrac{-B \pm \sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}}{2A}$$
And we know that one of the roots of each are the same. So for some choices of the signs on the two square roots, we have
$$\dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} = \dfrac{-B \pm \sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}}{2A}$$
Multiply through by the denominators and isolate one of the square roots:
$$\pm A\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} = bA-aB \pm a\sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}$$
Squaring both sides gives
$$A^2b^2 - 4A^2ac = (bA-aB)^2 \pm 2a(bA-aB)\sqrt{B^2 - 4AC} + a^2B^2 - 4a^2AC$$
Solving for the remaining root, assuming that $a(bA-aB) \ne 0$:
$$\sqrt{B^2 - 4AC} = \pm\dfrac{A^2b^2 - 4A^2ac - a^2B^2 + 4a^2AC - (bA-aB)^2}{2a(bA-aB)}$$
But all the variables are integers, so the right hand side is a rational number!
If $\sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}$ is rational, then so are the roots $\dfrac{-B \pm \sqrt{B^2 - 4AC}}{2A}$ of $q$. But we are told that $p$ and $q$ share a non-rational root (either irrational or non-real), a contradiction. Our assumption that $a(bA-aB) \ne 0$ must be wrong. Since $a\ne 0$, we must have $$bA=aB$$ so either $b = B = 0$ or $\frac aA = \frac bB$. Let $r = \frac aA$, and either way we have $a = rA, b = rB$. If you now substitute for $a$ and $b$ in the original equality between the roots, you can quickly deduce that $c = rC$ as well, completing the proof.
